# Sumatoria de tiempo con ventana de servicio SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2017

tengo el siguiente problema:

Sacando la vida útil de un correo, tengo la medición de tiempo que se tardan en ser atendido en lo que se denomina hrs naturales... Ahora necesito hacer el conteo de tiempo de atención dentro de la ventana de servicio.
Anexo una imagen de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En este ejemplo el tiempo de atención es de 11:50 hrs y dentro de la venta de servicio serian solo 50 min.

Mi medición actual es:

```
ISNULL(DATEDIFF(ss,[dateTime], (MIN([Atencion]))),0)
```

Hasta aqui me arroja los las hrs naturales, ya hice muchos ajustes y por mas que eh intentado no logro llegar a una solución.

cabe mencionar que mi código para ventana de servicio es:

```
CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [dateTime]) IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
             AND DATEPART(hour, [dateTime]) BETWEEN 7 AND 21
             THEN 1

        ELSE 0
    END
```

Lo que tenia como idea "estable" era contabilizar el tiempo por sección, de [dateTime] hasta corte de ventana y de ahí sumar el otro tiempo generado de la apertura hasta la [Atencion] ... Pero no veo la forma de digitarlo.

Ese es una bloqueo y falta hacer uno de fuera de la venta y contabilizarlo de la apertura hasta su atención (ese seria el segundo CASE de este WHEN).

Ejem: un correo que registrara a las 00:00hrs y atendido a las 8:40hrs, solo tendría 40 min de atención (2400 seg)

Comment: Puede haber varios intervalos sin atención? Puedes poner varios datos de muestra en forma de inserts?

Comment: Eh ahí el uno de los detalles. [dateTime] y [Atencion] son los únicos datos que tenemos "fijos" no tengo mas información como para desglosar, por eso la "ventana" es algo que quedo de esa forma, validación por 1 y 0 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dejo una función que puede funcionar para calcular el tiempo de forma adecuada. Sin embargo, tiene un bug cuando el horario de atención está fuera del rango de 8am a 9pm.

```
CREATE TABLE #Servicios(
        [datetime]  datetime,
        [Atencion]  datetime
);

INSERT INTO #Servicios
VALUES( '20191016 20:50', '20191017 8:40'),
      ( '20191017 00:00', '20191017 8:40'),
      ( '20191017 06:00', '20191018 8:40');
SELECT [datetime]
    , Atencion
    , --Obtenemos la diferencia total entre ambos tiempos en minutos
      DATEDIFF( MI, [datetime], [Atencion]) 
      -- Multiplicamos por 660 (11 horas por 60) minutos que son el tiempo fuera de horario de atención
      -- Hacemos la resta de 8 horas a los tiempos para que el horario de atención quede en el mismo día natural.
      -- Lo restamos a la diferencia total
    - ( 660 * (DATEDIFF( DD, DATEADD( HH, -8, [datetime]), DATEADD( HH, -8, [Atencion])))) 
      -- Al restar 8 horas, todo el horario de servicio queda hasta antes de la 1pm, por lo que queda fuera es de servicios fuera de horario
      -- Si pasa la 1pm, tomamos la hora de inicio, sacamos su diferencia en minutos desde la medianoche y le restamos 13 horas (780 minutos) que es el horario de servicio
      -- Ese tiempo lo sumamos para reducir del día completo que habíamos restado en la operación anterior
    + CASE WHEN CAST( DATEADD( HH, -8, [datetime]) AS time) > '13:00' THEN DATEDIFF( MI, '00:00', CAST( DATEADD( HH, -8, [datetime]) AS time)) - 780 ELSE 0 END
      -- Si pasa la 1pm, tomamos la hora de inicio, sacamos su diferencia en minutos desde la medianoche 
      -- y lo restamos al total de minutos en el día para saber cuanto tiempo se completó antes de iniciar el horario de servicio.
    + CASE WHEN CAST( DATEADD( HH, -8, Atencion) AS time) > '13:00' THEN 1440 - DATEDIFF( MI, '00:00', CAST( DATEADD( HH, -8, Atencion) AS time)) ELSE 0 END
FROM #Servicios

GO 
DROP TABLE #Servicios
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta y disculpa la demora. Me surge unas duda... trate de entenderlo pero no quiero obviar esta situación... ¿porque la multiplicación x 660?¿porque mayor a 13hrs? Saludos!

Comment: Acabo de agregar comentarios al código para que quede más claro.

Comment: Muchas gracias... Ya me queda claro y ya hice un par de modificaciones... esto me sirvió mucho =)

Comment: me salio una nueva duda que no quisiera dar por hecho: ya haciendo esto para 'CASE' me topo que tengo casos con de venta de apertura de 7am en vez de 8am. En ese caso ya modifique todo, pero mi única duda es en la parte de la resta de 8Hrs "para que quede en el mismo día natural" de acuerdo a tus comentarios... en este 'CASE' quedaría igual o si seria poner 7 HRS? espero puedas responder, gracias.

Comment: Si la apertura es a las 7am, restas 7 horas en vez de 8 en todas las operaciones que lo involucran.

Comment: Eso pensaba, solo quería cerciorarme, gracias =)